How to increase or decrease lv_line opacity after it is drawn using lvgl v9?
I have created a tick arc using raw pixel coordinates and set the initial opacity to 30% using lv_style_t. I aim to increase or decrease opacity within the animation callback. How can I do that?
I tried using lv_obj_set_style_opa. Since I created a circle arc using 20 lv_line objects and lv_line has a bounding box, the opacity change affects all the other lv_line objects that fall within that box.
